# Occassional or Frequent CHECK_NRPE: Error – Could not complete SSL handshake

Tags: nagios, nrpe

My Nagios/NRPE is configured and working as expected for a few years now.  Occasionally or sometimes even very frequently in a day I get "CHECK_NRPE: Error – Could not complete SSL handshake".  Is there a way to ignore this error as Nagios starts sending alerts only to recover the next minute.

Answer (score 0):

Increase some combination of the plugin timeout and the service `check_interval`, `retry_interval`, and/or `max_check_attempts`.